# req.user data from Passport JS not passed to Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm building an app with an Express/Node backend and Angular JS for the front end. Kinda new to using this stack and I'm having a hard time receiving the data in an Angular Service + Controller

Backend: Users can authenticate with Facebook using Passport JS that attaches a users object to every request. I opened up an endpoint that checks if req.user exists, like so:

```
app.get('/checklogin', function(req,res,next){

if(req.user){

  console.log("we found a user!!!");

  console.log("name:" + req.user.displayName);
  console.log("user id" + req.user.id);

  return res.status(201).json(req.user);

} else {

  console.log("there is no user logged in");


} 

});
```

If the req.user exists, so the user is authenticated, it sends a JSON response.

What I'm trying to do is in Angular is sending a http.get to this /checklogin endpoint and handle the response. I want to bind to the scope if the user is authenticated (req.user exists or not), and if so bind displayName and Id as well, and hide show nav links and pages.

But my setup in Angular hits the API endpoint but doesnt seem to receive any data????:

```
.service("Login", function($http){

    this.isLoggedIn = function(){  

        return $http.get("/checklogin")

            .then(function(response){

             console.log(response)

                return response;

            }, function(response){

                console.log("failed to check login");

            });

    };


})
.controller("mainController", function($scope, Login){


    Login.isLoggedIn()

        .then(function(doc){

            console.log(doc);
            console.log(doc.data);

        }, function(response){

            alert(response);

        });

})
```

the console.log(doc) and console.log(doc.data) don't log anything...... What am I doing wrong here?????

More info: the mainController is loaded in the index.html file:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--load jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--load Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--load Angular JS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <!--latest compiled and minified Bootstap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--link custom CSS file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- NAVBAR ================== ---->        
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="nav-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Votely</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/auth/facebook" target="_top">Sign in with Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="/logout">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>    

<!-- Dynamically render templates Angular JS -->
<div class="container" ng-view>

</div>


</body>
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It hits the API alright, but have you checked if the API actually returns a result? Maybe try using Postman or something

Comment: Does your server return any data? maybe `req.user` is empty

Comment: I can actually a response like this in the browser: {"id":"179884","displayName":"John Doe","name":{},"provider":"facebook","_raw":"{\"name\":\"Joh‌​n Doe\",\"id\":\"179884\"}","_json":{"name":"John Doe","id":"179884"}}

Answer (score 1):

You should return a promise from service if you are using `then` inside controller i.e.

```
.service("Login", function($http){

    this.isLoggedIn = function(){  

        return $http.get("/checklogin");
    };
```

Comment: Hi Aman, I changed the service to this, but the controller still doesnt log any data. Anything I'm doing wrong inside my controller?? I see everytime i refresh the page, it hits the API, so the $http.get inside my service works, but nothing happens in my controller it seems......

Comment: yeah, it's sending a response in this format: {"id":"179884","displayName":"John Doe","name":{},"provider":"facebook","_raw":"{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"id\":\"179884\"}","_json":{"name":"John Doe","id":"179884"}}

Answer (score 1):

`.isLoggedIn` function in your service should looks like this:

```
this.isLoggedIn = function(){
    return $http.get("/checklogin");
}
```

Comment: Hi Tilekbekov, I changed the service to this, but the controller still doesnt console log any data. Anything I'm doing wrong inside my controller??

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I got it working now. I was using the browser in Cloud 9 IDE and the server was sending a 503 response, not sure why. It works now in Chrome and Firefox etc. after I set the service to return a promise!